# Is $f(2)=\dfrac{1}{4}?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be a meromorphic function analytic at $0$ satisfying $f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\dfrac{n}{2n+1}~\forall~n\ge 1.$

**Question:** Is $f(2)=\dfrac{1}{4}?$

My attempt: By the identity theorem $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2+z}$ in the domain where $f$ is defined. If $f$ is defined at $2$ then it's true.

Let $f$ be not defined at $2.$ Then in a nbd of $2,$$f$ has the laurent series representation as $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{(z-2)+4}=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(1+\dfrac{z-2}{4}\right)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(1-\dfrac{z-2}{4}+...\right)\implies 2$ is a removable singular point, a contradiction since $f$ is meromorphic.

So $f$ is defined at $2$ and so $f(2)=\dfrac{1}{4}?.$

Am I right? Is there any easier method?

Comment: If the question aks whether $f(2)=\frac{1}{4}$, I guess it is defined at $2$. But as you observed, it is an removable singularity in the worst case scenario.

Comment: @julien I wondered about that too, but [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function): "$f$ meromorphic on $D$" means $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ minus a set of isolated points, which are *poles* for $f$. And if Wikipedia says so, it must be true: removable singularities are not allowed.

Comment: @julien It is meromorphic on $\mathbb C$ minus 0,1 according to the Wikipedia definition. However it is not meromorphic on $\mathbb C$. And in the OP the function is said to be meromorphic on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @julien I agree that it's mostly a matter of convention, but disagree with your last point. The words *meromorphic* and *holomorphic* are not synonymous. A function is meromorphic on the plane if it is holomorphic on the plane minus a discrete set of points, each of which is a pole.

Comment: @user75064 I know the difference between holomorphic and meromorphic...I said that because you said that $1/z$ above was not meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, so I was trying to figure out what you meant. But we both know what a meromorphic function is, so I think there is no need to keep commenting.

Comment: Of course we both know, but the Math.SE content is also meant for  posterity.  So I'll  clarify what I meant: the function $1/z$, restricted to $\mathbb C\setminus \{0,1\}$, does not qualify as a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$, at least according to Wikipedia definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid considering both cases by introducing $g(z)=f(z)-\dfrac{1}{2+z}$. Since $g$ is meromorphic, and its zeroes have a point of accumulation inside of its domain, it follows that $g$ is identically zero (where defined). Therefore, $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $2$, which implies that it's defined at $2$. Conclusion $f(2)=1/4$ follows.